# ¿Como puedo hacer un find para buscar sobre un ObjectID en mongoose?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Por ejemplo tengo dos modelos en mongoose:

```
var Persona = {
   nombre: "Luis",
   carros:{
     type: Schema.ObjectId,
     ref:'Carro'
   },
  apellidos:"Colx Redex"
}

var Carro = {
  modelo:"FX-200",
  velocidad:"300km/h",
  marca:"Nissan"
}
```

Entonces como hago una busqueda en el modelo persona pero que tambien abarque el modelo carro.... ejemplo:

```
Persona.find({persona.carros.marca: "Nissan"}, function(err, docs){

});
```

Cuando lo que realmente esta guardado en el modelo Persona es solo el ObjectId("5b93f9ee75323d09084af622") de el carro....

Espero cualquier ayuda, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar haciendo:

```
Persona.find().populate({
path: 'Carro',
match: {marca: 'Nissan'}
})
.exec()
.then(resultado => console.log(resultado))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```